# How to use "ln" create link for directories on linux?

Tags: linux, hyperlink, directory, symbols

I tried linux command line "ln", seems it couldn't do this:

```
mkdir -p test1/test2/test3
ln -s test4 test1 #I wish to create test4 as symbolic link to test1
find test4
```

The result is weird:

```
$ls test1
test2 test4
```

Well, test4 is a subdirectory of test1, not a link to test4.

It didn't achieve what I expected. How should I achieve this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change the position of arguments `ln [-fiqRrv] old new`. The first position is original file/folder e the second is the symbolic link. Try this, that will create a symbolic link in `test4` to `test1`

```
ln -s test1 test4
```

more in : [ln documentation](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/ln.1.asp)